# How to use combobox in other function in tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables

I am using python to create a simple GUI using tkinter. It has a `combobox` and a `button`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import json

def identifier_button_callback():
    identifier_combobox_value = identifier_combobox.get()

def main():
    global identifier_combobox

    app = tk.Tk()
    app.geometry('700x500')
    app.title("My GUI")

    # Identifier Combo Box and Label
    identifier_label = tk.Label(app, text="Identifier")
    identifier_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

    identifier_combobox = ttk.Combobox(app, values=['group', 'gen', 'Location'])
    identifier_combobox.grid(column=0, row=1)

    identifier_button = Button(app, text="OK", command=identifier_button_callback)
    identifier_button.grid(column=4, row=1)

    app.mainloop()


main()
```

I want to get the value of `identifier_combobox` in button callback but I cannot use the combobox in button callback. I tried making it `global` by putting `global identifier_combobox` in main function but it didnt worked. Can anyone please tell me how can I resolve it. Thanks

Comment: try using classes or write the entire code outside `main`. your problem of global varaibles will be solved. Besides that, you need to place `global identifier_combobox` in the `callback` function

Comment: Your cod works for me!